# How to make a div look like tabbed pane without any tab functionality?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is rectangular with some cute rounded corners. This is the appearence of it;

[image: no-tab]

But, what I should do is, put the header in a tab but it wount be clickable. Just the looks.This is the way it should look

[image: with tab]

Is there an easy way to do this? Or should I make the background an image? The div and the header is typical divs with height, width etc. The header has an image only. I could really use some suggestions. I would love to get some help with the CSS of it. It is Openx so it is kind of hard to me to understand each line of code in the project. I am very new at this.

Comment: Did you find these printscreen on a website? If yes, try to look at the source code and see how they did.

Comment: No, first one is mine, the other one is done by a graphics specialist so that I can make it look like his design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done completely without javascript, just plain old css..

If you have the  markup

```
 <div id="stuff">
     <h1>title</h1>
     Lorem ispum dolor sit amet
 </div>
```

(I have an `<h1>`, but in your case it would be an Image. Except for that there should be no difference)

Then a css like the following should do the trick:

```
 #stuff {
     margin: 100px;
     position:relative;
     background-color: silver;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 30px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
     border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
     padding: 30px;
 }

 #stuff h1 {
     position: absolute;
     top: -40px;
     height: 40px;
     right: 0px;
     left: 50%;
     background-color: silver;
     padding: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
     border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
 }
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4RPhu/

basically you're styling the div, and then positioning the "Tab" absolutely relative to the div, with negative top value so it sticks out, and then simply on the left. Just adjust the values according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you I made all the other things except for the position relative and absolute but now I added it and it looks just like the design. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Without tab functionality" actually makes this a lot easier. There are so many ways to do this, I'll offer one: http://jsfiddle.net/bpWXE/

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab tab1">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab tab2">Tab 1</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Content</p>  
    <p>Content</p>  
    <p>Content</p>  
</div>
```

```
.tabs {
    text-align:right;
}
.tab {
    padding:.5em 3em;   
    display:inline-block;
}
.tab2,
.content{
   background:#ccc;   
   border:2px solid #aaa;
   border-radius:10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.tab2 {
   border-bottom-color:#ccc; /* same as .content background */
   margin-bottom:-2px; /* .content border width */
   border-radius:20px 10px 0 0; /* tweak to preference */
}
```

The idea here is that you're moving the tab(s) down to cover up the top border of the content pane (which you can also do in a number of ways).

As I apparently keep saying, there are *tons* of ways to accomplish this with CSS, you absolutely do not need a background image.

Comment: This would work, but It's a bit too much overhead In my opinion (the additional `<div class="tabs">[...]</div>` with the tabs separated from the content doesn't seem that intuitive to me. If you want to add a tab you have to modify two parts of the code.. Then again, it's a matter of personal preference. I like to stick have to modify the code in 1 part to make 1 modification. But it works, and that's the point.

Comment: You can certainly do this with bare-bones markup, but you haven't provided the markup you're actually working with. You said you wanted "ideas". Remember, markup is for content - CSS is presentation. You should avoid writing markup based solely on what you want it to *look* like, you can (almost) always achieve your goal with only CSS. I don't know what you actual content *is*. Does this suit you better?: http://jsfiddle.net/bpWXE/1/

Comment: Ehm.. I'm not the original question asker.. I was just sa<ing.. (and yes, I think the second one is better, by the way..). And What you're saying is exactly my point: you have a `<div>` that has no "meaning", it#s just for presentation: the tabs are part of the "content", so putting them in a sperate `<div>` is already enforcing  presentation in the markup...

Comment: Ah my mistake, I didn't notice. By the way you posted it sounded like you were the question asker. Yes, I used divs for demonstation purposes, this isn't a real document that has any meaning. The extra classes are not necessary, but I used them to hopefully make the CSS shorter and clearer to understand for OP.

Comment: Thank you, too. As you wrote, I put the header div, put it on top of the content div, arranged the heights so that the border wouldn't be visible. And it worked :) Just changed the two divs' styles.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, using a combination of `div`s next to eachother, with a careful use of the following:

```
border-top-left-radius
border-top-right-radius
border-bottom-left-radius
border-bottom-right-radius
```

You will want to make sure that you take into account webkit and mozilla radii too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery, assigning a click function to each tab div and swapping the background out on the currently selected one / the new one when clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

// set to default tab number when page loads
var current_tab = $('.tab_div_class:eq(0)');

$(function($) {
  $('.tab_div_class').click(function() {
    current_tab.css('background-image', 'url(images/tab_not_selected.jpg)'); // set to whatever you want the bg image to be for the off state
    current_tab = $(this);
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/tab_selected.jpg)'); // set to selected state background.
  });
});

</script>
```